# unable to cast object of type system.int32 to type system.string combobox fill from database

Tags: c#, database, combobox

I get the 'unable to cast object of type system.int32 to type system.string' error message when I try to populate a combobox from a datatable. The data is an int type (used as an identity column) the class is called on form load.

```
void fillComboRef()
{
    string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
    string Query = "select * from customersTBL ";
    SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring);
    SqlCeCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase);
    SqlCeDataReader myReader;
    try
    {
        conDataBase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string sRef = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Reference"));

            comboRef.Items.Add(sRef);
        }

        //displays a system error message if a problem is found
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
        string Query = "select Reference from customersTBL ";
        SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring);
        SqlCeCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        SqlCeDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                comboRef.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(myReader.GetInt32(0)));

                //string sRef = Convert.ToString(myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Reference")));

//                comboRef.Items.Add(sRef);
            }

            //displays a system error message if a problem is found
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int ordinal = myReader.GetOrdinal("Reference");
int reference = myReader.GetInt32(ordinal);

string sRef = reference.ToString();
```

Comment: I get two errors, 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetInt32(int) has some invalid arguements, and cannot convert from string to int

Comment: Can you share the DDL for customersTBL?

Comment: sqlCe 3.5, is that what you mean ?

Comment: I'm referring to the script to create the customersTBL.

Comment: I created it in the database explorer

Comment: Well if you can find a way to script the table in your tool I can help you more. Other than that, perhaps try putting the GetInt32() and GetOrdinal() calls on separate lines, that may give more insight into where the problem is.

Comment: I updated my answer to show the code using multiple lines. Try this and see exactly which line is failing. This may help figure out what is going on.